# TaggedImage(java.lang.Object pix, JSONObject tags) - What is JSONObject tags here? What kind of parameters are needed for input to this method?

Tags: java, json, bufferedimage, tiff, sci-java

I am trying to implement the below code where I attempt to convert a BufferedImage bufferedImage1, to a TaggedImage (TIFF).

I do not understand how to give the value "tags". I know it is a JSONObject, but what kind of parameters should there be in this JSONObject?

I took a look at the [Javadoc](http://javadoc.scijava.org/Micro-Manager-Core/mmcorej/TaggedImage.html#tags) for this but it's not very explanatory... and as I am just starting to learn this, it is difficult for me to grasp... Would be great if some one could give me some pointers as to how I can go about this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
/**
 *  Convert this Image to a TaggedImage and return it.
 * @return 
 */
public TaggedImage asTaggedImage (BufferedImage  bufferedImage1) {
            return new TaggedImage(getPixels(bufferedImage1), tags);

}
```

Comment: few tags that I am aware of are DocumentName
PageName, XPosition, YPosition, T4Options

you can add them in your code as JSONObject tags = new JSONObject(); 
tags.put("DocumentName", "sample");

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pulkit

Comment: If this answers ypur question shall i put it as an answer?